# Error (aveces) al hacer dump con python task desde servidor linux a windows con docker

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, docker

Con Invoke hago un dump a mi base de datos haciendo uso de docker. y en ocasiones que digamos de 10 intentos 1 funciona y los otros 9 arroja un error
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 5737: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''
at line 1

```
@task(build_db_local)

def wait_running_db_local(c):
print('Esperando DB ...')

def _db_status_local():
    return c.run('mysqlcheck -s -h localhost -u ozm -p lab --password=ozm', hide='err', warn=True).exited

status = _db_status_local()
i = 0
while True:
    if status == 0:
        break

    i += 1
    if (i > 10):
        raise ValueError("Fallo en la creacion de la BD error: ", status)

    print('.', end='', flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
    status = _db_status_local()


@task(drop_db_local, wait_running_db_local)
def pull_running_prod_local(c):
    c.run('ssh root@192.168.1.66 '
          '"cd work && ~/.local/bin/docker-compose run --rm mariadb dump"'
          f'| mysql -h localhost -u ozm --password=ozm')
```

Comment: te lo he vuelto a modificar

Answer (score 0):

Creemos un Dockerfile para crear una instancia de contenedor mariadb:

```
docker-mariadb git:(master) ✗ cat Dockerfile

FROM mariadb:latest

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD test
```

Nuestro archivo docker usará la última imagen de mariadb y también llenaremos una variable env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD a través de la ENV VALOR CLAVE El comando más detallado se da a continuación:

Construyamos la imagen MariaDB usando comando de compilación de Docker

```
 docker-mariadb git:(master) ✗ docker build -t linoxide/mariadb:v1 .

Sending build context to Docker daemon 34.82 kB

Step 1 : FROM mariadb:latest

latest: Pulling from library/mariadb

…

Successfully built a33014d19bcb
```

Una vez que la imagen está construida, podemos usarla para ejecutar nuestro contenedor, así:

```
 ~ docker run -d linoxide/mariadb:v1

35d67d1643b44f1063500e38805e5c54545540c37d1c0179acb5cc953076ee09
```

**Nota:**

Si no desea usar Dockerfile, puede ejecutar un contenedor simplemente usando una línea de comando, como se muestra a continuación, pero se prefiere Dockerfile ya que nos permite guardar nuestra configuración de construcción, por ejemplo, en nuestro caso, era solo una simple variable env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD pero puedes imaginar una situación con un montón de configuraciones.

Hagamos una lista de nuestros contenedores:

```
 ~ Docker ps

Container id        image                 command                  created             status              ports               names

35d67d1643b4        linoxide/mariadb:v1   "docker-entrypoint.sh"   5 minutes ago       up 5 minutes        3306/tcp            silly_davinci
```

Conectando a nuestro contenedor bash usando el ID del contenedor (mira el resultado del último comando arriba). Una vez conectados, podemos iniciar el servidor de la base de datos usando mysql –usuario = raíz –contraseña = $ MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD; en el momento de escribir mysql sigue siendo el punto de entrada para iniciar el servidor mariadb:

```
~ docker exec -it 35d67d1643b4 bash

root@35d67d1643b4:/# mysql --user=root --password=test

Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or g.

Your MariaDB connection id is 2

Server version: 10.1.19-MariaDB-1~jessie mariadb.org binary distribution

 

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

 

Type 'help;' or 'h' for help. Type 'c' to clear the current input statement.

 

MariaDB [(none)]> show databases;

+--------------------+

| Database           |

+--------------------+

| information_schema |

| mysql              |

| performance_schema |

+--------------------+

3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

 

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Use ‘salir’ para salir de la consola mariadb y una segunda ‘salida’ para salir del contenedor bash.

Para comprobar los registros del servidor, utilice registros de docker docker_id mando.

Use ‘salir’ para salir de la consola mariadb y una segunda ‘salida’ para salir del contenedor bash.

Para comprobar los registros del servidor, utilice registros de docker docker_id mando.

**Notas:**

A continuación se muestran algunas variables env que podemos usar, por ejemplo, en nuestro Dockerfile:

> MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD [mandatory]: para especificar una contraseña de usuario root del servidor de base de datos

> MYSQL_DATABASE [optional]: si queremos crear una base de datos específica por nombre al inicio del servidor db

> MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD [optional]: si queremos crear un nuevo usuario al inicio, entonces podemos especificar el nombre y la contraseña del usuario

> MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD [optional]: si es igual a sí, el contenedor comenzará a permitir una contraseña en blanco para el usuario root

> MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD [optional]: asigne una contraseña aleatoria al usuario root al inicio, la contraseña se imprimirá en el STDOUT

**Conectando a mariadb desde fuera**

Ahora que hemos creado un servidor de base de datos, podemos atacarlo desde afuera, idealmente, para nosotros en este artículo podemos usar otro contenedor para hacer eso. Entonces, aquí reutilizaré mi aplicación nodejs de muestra creada en un artículo de vistas previas para disparar un contenedor. En primer lugar, siga adelante y verifique la dirección IP de nuestro contenedor MariaDB mirando la línea «IPAddress» en la salida del comando a continuación:

```
 msg-api git:(master) ✗ docker inspect 35d67d1643b4

"IPAddress": "172.17.0.2"
```

Tenga en cuenta que cambiaré la dirección IP de mi aplicación nodejs y crearé una nueva imagen; para obtener más detalles, consulte mi artículo de vistas previas como se mencionó anteriormente; de ​​lo contrario, puede seguir los pasos a continuación, ya que ya he sacado la ventana acoplable. de la imagen a la ventana acoplable, la ventana acoplable la encontrará y la extraerá de la ventana acoplable:

```
msg-api git:(master) ✗ docker build -t linoxide/msg-api:v0.0.5 .

Sending build context to Docker daemon 9.728 kB

Step 1 : FROM node:latest

…

Successfully built e0f9596397a3
```

Ahora ejecutemos un contenedor docker con port-forward para poder atacarlo desde afuera:

```
 msg-api git:(master) ✗  docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name msg-api linoxide/msg-api:v0.0.5

8f70e4261bc6676467fe4f59fc67fa7e4659860d20f2e55dd3dec48ed3ee0d70
```

verifiquemos el estado de nuestra aplicación usando el punto final ‘/ ping’:

```
 docker-mariadb git:(master) ✗ curl localhost:8080/ping

hello there! I m up and running!%
```

Ahora me voy a conectar al servidor mariadb e insertar algunos datos:

```
msg-api git:(master) ✗ docker exec -it 35d67d1643b4 bash

root@35d67d1643b4:/# mysql --user=root --password=test

Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or g.

Your MariaDB connection id is 8

Server version: 10.1.19-MariaDB-1~jessie mariadb.org binary distribution

 

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

 

Type 'help;' or 'h' for help. Type 'c' to clear the current input statement.

 

MariaDB [(none)]> show databases;

+--------------------+

| Database           |

+--------------------+

| information_schema |

| k8smysqldb         |

| mysql              |

| performance_schema |

+--------------------+

4 rows in set (0.04 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> use k8smysqldb;

Reading table information for completion of table and column names

You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed

MariaDB [k8smysqldb]> insert into messages values 'first faked msg over here';

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''first faked msg over here'' at line 1

MariaDB [k8smysqldb]> insert into messages(text) values('first faked msg over here');

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [k8smysqldb]> insert into messages(text) values('Second faked msg over here');

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [k8smysqldb]>
```

Ahora, voy a usar nuestra aplicación nodejs para recuperar estos datos usando msg-api / all endpoint:

```
docker-mariadb git:(master) ✗ curl localhost:8080/msg-api/all

[{"id":1,"text":"first faked msg over here"},{"id":2,"text":"Second faked msg over here"}]%
```

**Detener y eliminar el contenedor mariadb**

Una vez que haya terminado con sus contenedores docker y desee eliminarlos, simplemente ejecute:

> docker ps –a para enumerar todos los contenedores

> busque los ID de los contenedores que desea eliminar

> asegúrese de detenerlos primero, de lo contrario obtendrá un error, para hacerlo, estibador detenga your_container_id1 your_container_id1 …

> entonces corre docker rm your_container_id1 your_container_id1… para borrarlos

**Conclusión**

hemos visto cómo poner en marcha un servidor MariaDB utilizando un contenedor docker. También hemos visto cómo conectarse al contenedor en sí y ejecutar el servidor de la base de datos usando el programa mysql (sí, ya que mariadb es totalmente compatible con mysql) y cómo comunicarse con la base de datos mariadb desde otro contenedor.

**¿Cómo corregir el error de MySQL 1064 (5 métodos)?**

Si ya tiene una idea de lo que está causando su error de MySQL 1064, puede simplemente saltar a la resolución para su situación específica. Sin embargo, si no está seguro de por qué se ha producido el error, la estrategia más sencilla es probar primero la solución más fácil.

En ese caso, sugerimos probar las cinco soluciones más probables en el siguiente orden.

**1. Corregir comandos mal escritos**

Lo bueno de los errores tipográficos de MySQL es que son la explicación más simple de los problemas de sintaxis, como el error 1064. Desafortunadamente, también pueden ser los más tediosos de corregir. En términos generales, su mejor opción es corregir manualmente su código y buscar cualquier error que pueda haber cometido.

Le sugerimos que utilice el Manual de MySQL como referencia mientras lo hace, comprobando cualquier cosa de la que no esté seguro. Como puede imaginar, esto puede llevar bastante tiempo, especialmente si ha estado trabajando en la línea de comandos de MySQL durante un tiempo o si es nuevo en esta tarea.

Una alternativa a la comprobación manual de su trabajo es emplear una herramienta como EverSQL:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esta solución, usted puede simplemente introducir su MySQL para comprobar si hay errores automáticamente. Sin embargo, tenga en cuenta que estas plataformas no siempre son perfectas y es posible que desee validar los resultados usted mismo.

**2. Reemplazar comandos obsoletos**

A medida que las plataformas crecen y cambian, algunos comandos que eran útiles en el pasado son reemplazados por otros más eficientes. MySQL no es una excepción. Si está trabajando en su base de datos después de una actualización reciente o ha hecho referencia a una fuente obsoleta durante su trabajo, es posible que uno o más de sus comandos ya no sean válidos.

Puede comprobar si este es el caso utilizando el Manual de Referencia de MySQL. Encontrará menciones de comandos que han quedado obsoletos por cada versión de MySQL en las secciones relevantes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez que haya determinado qué comando es el que probablemente está causando el problema, simplemente puede usar la función»buscar y reemplazar» para eliminar el comando obsoleto y añadirlo a la nueva versión. Por ejemplo, si estaba usando el `storage_engine` y descubre que ya no funciona, simplemente podría reemplazar todas las instancias con el nuevo comando `default_storage_engine`.

**3. Designación de palabras reservadas**

En MySQL, usar una palabra reservada fuera de contexto resultará en un error de sintaxis, ya que será interpretado como incorrecto. Sin embargo, todavía puede usar palabras reservadas como le plazca conteniéndolas dentro de los backticks, de esta manera: `select`

Cada versión de MySQL tiene sus propias palabras reservadas, que puede leer en el Manual de Referencia de MySQL. Una rápida búsqueda y reemplazo debería permitirle resolver este problema si cree que puede estar causando el error 1064.

**4. Añadir datos que faltan**

Si su última consulta MySQL intenta referenciar información en una base de datos y no puede encontrarla, obviamente se encontrará con problemas. En el caso de que ninguna de las soluciones anteriores resuelva su error de MySQL 1064, puede ser el momento de buscar datos perdidos.

**5. Use el modo de compatibilidad para transferir bases de datos de WordPress**

Esta última solución de error 1064 no es tan sencilla como las demás de nuestra lista. Sin embargo, si está migrando su sitio WordPress a un nuevo host o lo está moviendo a un servidor diferente, deberá tomar medidas adicionales para evitar causar problemas con su base de datos.

La solución más sencilla es utilizar un plugin de migración que incluya un modo de compatibilidad, como WP Migrate DB:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto habilitará una función de detección automática que asegurará que la última copia de seguridad y base de datos de su sitio sea compatible con múltiples versiones de MySQL. Puede acceder a la configuración del modo de compatibilidad navegando a Herramientas > Migrar base de datos > Opciones avanzadas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Marque la casilla de Compatible con versiones anteriores de MySQL antes de iniciar la migración de su sitio. De esta manera, podrá evitar cualquier problema durante el proceso

Comment: Esta excelente la información, pero mi contenedor funciona. el problema surge en ocasiones que no me genera una copia de la bd del servidor a mi computador.

Comment: ha pues entonces ya ni idea lo siento, puede ser que tengas muchos espacios en tu disco, o algo en cuanto hardwared?

Comment: bueno si la genera, pero incompleta, siempre se queda en las ultimas 5 tablas. Gracias, igual es buena información

Comment: de nada espero que te sirva :)

Comment: espera que te meto mas información sobre las posibles errores de 1064